# Proper way to use divs to align divisions of web page on left or right side

Tags: css, html

I am getting back into web development for a project and I am trying to learn how to setup my divs so some elements are left aligned and others are right aligned. Many moons ago before 's were around I would use a table and set the alignment of the cells but I can't seem to find the equivalent with div's.

In the below html code I am trying to make the text "My Brand" be on the left and the "Link 1" and "Link 2" blocks of text to be on the right. All 3 blocks of text should be on the same line and be vertically aligned.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi Mom</title>


<style>
    .header
    {
    background-color:#BFEFFF;
    height:50px;
    }

    .tagline
    {
    color: #00A5D8;
       font-size: 20pt;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-indent: 20pt;
    display: inline;
    }

body
{
margin:0px;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body >

<div class="header"><div class="tagline"><p>My  Brand</p></div><div class="tagline"><p>Link 1</p></div><div class="tagline"><p>Link 2</p></div></div>

<div><center>
    blah blah
</center></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
   <div class="header"><div class="tagline1"><p >My  Brand</p></div><div class="tagline"><p>Link 2</p></div><div class="tagline"><p>Link 1</p></div></div>

<div><center>
    blah blah
</center></div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .header
{
background-color:#BFEFFF;
height:50px;


}

.tagline
{
color: #00A5D8;
   font-size: 20pt;
font-family: Helvetica Neue;
font-weight: bold;
vertical-align: middle;
text-indent: 20pt;
display: inline;
float:right;
width:300px;
}
 .tagline1
{
color: #00A5D8;
   font-size: 20pt;
font-family: Helvetica Neue;
font-weight: bold;
vertical-align: middle;
text-indent: 20pt;
display: inline;
float:left;
width:300px;
}


body
{
margin:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float:left` is your friend   :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` in the style of tagline.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CrSqk/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this .It will help you.

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:30%;float:left;">My Brand</div>
    <div style="width:30%;float:left;">Link1</div>
    <div style="width:30%;float:left;">Link2</div>
</div>
```